# Bootstrap5 Stretched-link doesn't work with a simple card

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a small problem, stretched-link doesn't want to work with my card, I tried everything from Bootstrap docs. Tried also removing buttons cause I've read that they don't "live well" with stretched-link. I use `django-bootstrap-v5` (is it good to use this btw.?)

This is my code:

```
       <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 81rem;">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a type="button" class="streched-link" href="{% url 'bloger:post' post.id %}">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="...">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8" style="max-height: 11rem;">
                    <div class="card-header d-flex bd-highlight">
                        <small class="text-muted p-1 flex-grow-1">Added {{ post.date_added|timesince:currentdate}} ago.</small>
                        <small class="text-muted p-1 flex-grow-3">Komentarze: {{ post.blogcomment_set.count }}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body" style="max-height: 10rem;">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{post.title|title}}</h4>
                        <p class="card-text" style="max-height: 8.4rem;"><i>{{post.truncated_text}}</i></p>
                        <a class="streched-link btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'bloger:post' post.id %}">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a silly question but have you also positioned the a.streched-link relatively? Card div should be by default but if not you might have to make some adjustments. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are miss-spelling stretched

Comment: oh my god, one hour of checking every possible combination and didn't see that XD thanks, code is now working.